# Cannot create a fragment with a corresponding REST endpoint in Jira

Tags: rest, jira, atlassian-sourcetree, atlassian-plugin-sdk, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am trying to create a custom web item that navigates to a link when clicking on it. Here is a screenshot of the way in which I have created the custom web item: 
[image]

I have also defined a REST endpoint as you can see in the following screenshot

[image]

Here is the corresponding code for my REST Endpoint that I have written in the script editor. The problem is that nothing works, even the string that I am writing to the log "THIS IS MOUNA'S TEST" is not displayed in the log. So when I click on the menu item "Mouna Bulk Summary", I get redirected to this error page. How can I fix this and make my fragment/REST endpoint work? 
[image]

```
import groovy.transform.BaseScript

import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate

import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap

import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl

import com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties

import com.atlassian.sal.api.UrlMode

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

import org.apache.log4j.Logger

@BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate

 

callFeaturePerformanceImpactAnalysis(httpMethod: "GET") { MultivaluedMap queryParams ->

    def log = Logger.getLogger("atlassian-jira.log")

    log.warn("THIS IS MOUNA'S TEST")

    def user = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext?.loggedInUser

    def issue = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueObject(queryParams.getFirst("issueId") as Long)

    def baseUrl = ScriptRunnerImpl.getOsgiService(ApplicationProperties).getBaseUrl(UrlMode.ABSOLUTE)

    def redirectUrl = "https://secapps.eur.ad.sag:9888/FPIA/?iTrac=${issue.key}&reporter=${user.key}&baseURL=${baseUrl}"

    Response.temporaryRedirect(URI.create(redirectUrl)).build()

}
```